# RNN layers in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ocr

I have model with RNN layers which is developed in tensorflow, and i am trying to implement it with keras functional API, i am able to define CNN layers but stuck with RNN and CTC layers.

How can i convert this tf code to Keras

````
# basic cells which is used to build RNN
numHidden = 256
cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=numHidden, state_is_tuple=True) for _ in range(2)]  # 2 layers
# stack basic cells
stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
# bidirectional RNN
# BxTxF -> BxTx2H
((fw, bw), _) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=stacked, cell_bw=stacked, inputs=rnnIn3d,
                                                dtype=rnnIn3d.dtype)
# BxTxH + BxTxH -> BxTx2H -> BxTx1X2H
concat = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([fw, bw], 2), 2)
# project output to chars (including blank): BxTx1x2H -> BxTx1xC -> BxTxC
kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, numHidden * 2, 79 + 1], stddev=0.1))
rnnOut3d = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value=concat, filters=kernel, rate=1, padding='SAME'), axis=[2])```
````

Comment: May be first you can refer [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) documentation and post a specific question if you are stuck at something.

Comment: Can i use bidirectional(lstm(64)) instead of these